# Azure Release Pipeline fails when try to pull image from ACR

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-container-registry

I try to use Azure pipelines for ci and cd.

1- My application image is built and pushed to azure container registry.

2- Release pipeline try to pull image from ACR it gets error.
Logs from container settings:

```
INFO  - Pulling image: registryname/repo:latest
ERROR - DockerApiException: Docker API responded with status code=InternalServerError, response={"message":"Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/registryname/repo/manifests/latest: unauthorized: incorrect username or password"}

ERROR - Pulling docker image registryname/repo:latest failed:
INFO  - Pulling image from Docker hub: registryname/repo:latest
ERROR - DockerApiException: Docker API responded with status code=NotFound, response={"message":"pull access denied for registryname/repo, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied"}

ERROR - Image pull failed: Verify docker image configuration and credentials (if using private repository)
INFO  - Stopping site appname because it failed during startup.
```

Ss from configuration:
[image]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: you just need to pass the valid container registry and the image name

Comment: I think my container registry is valid and image name is also right. Why did you think they are invalid?

Comment: Because the error message indicates that

Comment: I checked the credentials but it seems right however when I try to login from cmd like  docker login registryName, I get unauthorized: authentication required.

Comment: You need to create a service connection from azure DevOps or use the cli in order to authenticate with acr

Comment: I already have a service connection, azure devops has successfully pushed images to acr, but deploying it to app service is my problem.

Comment: @dcy Could you share some details about your build pipeline content and the settings in your release pipeline? Is there any possibility that your tags are mismatching? Please make sure the tag you tries to pull in release is the one pushed in build pipeline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the ACR to store the image and want to deploy the images in it to Azure Web App, you need to set the image name as ACRName.azurecr.io/image:tag, not just the image name and tag. And set the environment variables like:

> DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_USERNAME - The username for the ACR server.
> DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_URL - The full URL to the ACR server. (For
> example, https://my-server.azurecr.io.)
> DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_PASSWORD - The password for the ACR server.

And the credential should have enough permissions. When all things are OK, the container logs will look like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply but environment variables are defined like you said above. You wrote that credential should have enough permissions. How can I check that?

Comment: @dcy If you use the admin user and password of the ACR, then it already has enough permission. Actually, I think your problem is using the wrong image name.

Comment: Thanks it looks like you re right. My image name was wrong, now it is working.